# Getting list item index

Tags: android

Other than using listeners, is there any way by which i can get index of an item in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using 'getCheckedItemPosition' dont forget to set the choice mode to single in order to ensure only one item can be selected at a time.
ie via

`getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);`

And to answer your question : yes , this can be used without a listener.

Answer (score 1):

[indexOf](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29)?

Perhaps you mean ListView, in which case you may want [`getCheckedItemPosition`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#getCheckedItemPosition%28%29).

Comment: Suppose I have a list having 10 items. When the list control/cursor is in 5th position, I need to get index 5, that too, without using OnItemSelectedListener. is it possible?